# Google analytics is there any fields are available for eventID and eventURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

i am new to GA i am trying to implement GA like this on button click

```
var eventAction = "Click";
var eventLabel = "button text";
var eventValue = "https://developers.google.com/analytics";
gtag('event', eventAction, { 'event_category': eventCategory, 'event_label': eventLabel })
```

but the requirement is i have to implement

```
eventAction= "click"
eventLabel= "Button Text"
eventCategory = "Div class name"
eventID=ID = "Button ID"
eventURL= "https://developers.google.com/analytics" 
ga('send', 'event', 'click', 'Learn more', 'banner-container bannertextleft', 'ID-XXXXXXXX', '/';"
```

is there any way we can customize the GA events by adding like above ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The first example uses gtag object while the seconf example ga object. The second example is hardcoded and sending the values in a way. What you want to do now?

Answer (score 0):

No, your possible fields are:

- Category
- Action
- Label
- Value

You'll have to cram whatever extra metadata you need to into the label.

Documentation is here:  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068#Anatomy

Answer (score 0):

**No, you cannot insert extra fields in events**. The only 4 available are:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#event_fields

- `category` (string,required)
- `action` (string,required)
- `label` (integer,optional)
- `value` (integer,optional)

**However, you can use custom dimensions to extend data associated with events**.

- Create [`hit` scope custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)
- Set those dimensions before sending your events
- Send your events

So let's assume you've created `eventID`/`eventURL` as your 1st/2nd custom dimensions, code would look like:

```
ga('set', 'cd1', 'Button ID');
ga('set', 'cd2', 'https://developers.google.com/analytics');
ga('send', 'event',...
```

Then using the reporting or the [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) you can pull your event data along with your custom dimensions (eg with the API you would use `ga:dimensionXX` where `XX` is the dimension ID).

**About `eventURL`**: please note that by default events are automatically associated with the previously recorded pageview. So if `eventURL` represents the page events are fired on, you don't even need to implement this, it's already done. Just use the reporting or the API (`ga:pagePath`) to pull that info.